# Open modal when the user clicks a selec´s option

Tags: angular, select, modal-dialog

I have  component in my application, its options are generated with ng-options, but I need a separeted option iside the  that open a Modal. Any idea how to achieve this? Any help will be awsome, i really need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more element in your option like `+ add` and give a value say `-1` to it. On select you can check the value of selected item and if it's `-1` open the dialog.

Comment: Great! I´ll try that, Thanks!!